# CTRL-C handler not working properly

Tags: c, windows-7, handler, interrupt

This program

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

void INThandler(int);             

int  main(void)
{
   signal(SIGINT, INThandler);    

   char data[128];

   int n;

   while((n=read(0, data, 128)) > 0)
   {
   if(data[n] = '\n') break;
   }

   data[n] ='\0';

   printf("%s", data);

   return 0;
}

void  INThandler(int sig)
{
     char  c;

     signal(sig, SIG_IGN);             
     printf("OUCH, did you hit Ctrl-C?\n"    
            "Do you really want to quit? [y/n] ");
     c = getchar();                     
     if (c == 'y' || c == 'Y')          
         exit(0);                      
     else
      signal(SIGINT, INThandler);
}
```

Doesn't handle ctrl-c, but terminates at that input.
If I replace everything between the handler install and the return by

```
while (1)                          
Sleep(1);
```

the handler function is called and works but I want to have the read() in there.

EDIT: Looking back at this program, I noticed that I have

```
if(data[n] = '\n') break;
```

I wrote '=' instead of '==', but by using the later, it doesn't work properly and I don't understand why. Shouldn't it be a comparison to detect '\n'?
Also, I messed around with the buffer, but I can't make keep the input if I hit CTRL-C.

Answer (score 1):

The example code does not take into accounts two issues:

1. `read()` will abort it's work if its process receives a signal (see `man 2 read`)
2. It is only guaranteed for a few functions that they can be called savely from a signal handler function (see `man 7 signal`). `printf()`and `getch()` do not **not** belong to this set of "save" functions.

The first issue could be fixed using a more differentiated way to handle the value returned by `read()`. I should counts how much data had already been read, together with some smart adjustment of the buffer passed to `read()`.

Regarding the second issue, `read()` and `write()` are the functions of choice to perform input/output to/from a signal handler as those are listed to be "save" functions by the man-page mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the implementation of `read(2)` you use doesn't allow that. Here is what I get when I compile your program, execute it and press ^C:

```
$ ./program
^COUCH, did you hit Ctrl-C?
Do you really want to quit? [y/n] y
$
```

or if I answer n and enter some data:

```
$ ./program
^COUCH, did you hit Ctrl-C?
Do you really want to quit? [y/n] n
test
test
$
```

Since `read(2)` is a system call, it depends on the system you use. I use Linux (3.2.0-4-686-pae) and here it's behaving correctly. Maybe you should consider to use `scanf(3)` or `fread(3)` with `stdio(3)` instead, for the platform you're using (which I take to be [win32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows.h))? Or also use a different implementation, like the ones from *Cygwin* or *MinGW*?

Comment: I see, so it depends on the SO. So far I had no issues using Windows and then testing on Unix. Thank you.